# How would i assign distinct attribute value in a ComboBox datacontext?

Tags: wpf, linq, linq-to-sql, wpf-controls, dynamic-linq

I would like to show all distinct Category in a ComboBox named categoryList

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CategoryTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Category}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
...
 <ComboBox Name="catagoryList" VerticalAlignment="Top" SelectionChanged="categoryList_SelectionChanged" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CategoryTemplate}"/>
...
```

code behind:

```
this.categoryList.DataContext = ldc.Books.Select(b => b.Category).Distinct();
```

but, its not working. How can i do this? Or is there any other way to do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add [ToList()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx) to [Distinct()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx) and assign it to `ItemsSource`.

```
this.categoryList.ItemSource = ldc.Books.Select(b => b.Category).Distinct().ToList();
```